# How to loop check if there are zero rows in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

The question is in the title and where do you think I best put that code to trigger that  check? Thanks everyone.

Ps. The datagridview's row can vary and have different numbers of rows depending on the situation. So I think we need a loop to check if datagridview is empty or has no rows.

Comment: shouldn't require a loop, just do `datagridview1.RowCount == 0`. Where to put it depends on what you're needing it for.

Comment: There's also `datagridview1.Rows.Count` if that's more obvious to you. Both work.